# Updating old website links to new website links

Tags: seo

I am trying to update my old site with the new website but not sure how i can maintain the old links so google doesn't penalize. Please assist me on this

Answer (score 1):

Use the .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^old-page\.html$ /new-page-permalink/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

or

```
Redirect 301 /old-page.html http://www.domain.com/new-page-permalink/
```

Put in before wordpress's beginning comments or after wordpress's ending comments to ensure wordpress doesn't erase your redirects.